# Where to use the SSL certification files for your server domain?

Tags: ssl, security, ssl-certificate, domain

I was learning to create a Telegram bot and I had to get a server with HTTPS prefix in order to use my bot on Telegram.
I used free host, and a free domain, and a free net2FTP. So I can control nothing but my domain directories.

Right now, I'm on the last step to get a free SSL certification on my domain using SSLForFree and ZeroSSL. The problem is that they gave me an SSL certification files saying that all I need is to install them on my server, but all I did was just installing `certificate.crt` and `ca_bundle.crt` into my local machine. When I go to check the installation, it throws this error:

[ZeroSSL install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hjmY.png)

**[Note: my server name is not available in the list of ZeroSSL servers]
Server Name: aba.ae | Domain name: telebot0001.aba.vg**

Also, there is a file called `private.key`, I'm not sure what all of these things mean, but any idea how to fix that error?
I just need a server to upload my bot on it.

Comment: You ***can't*** install your own certificates on a webserver you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

most likely it is little difficult to suggest anything without knowing the OS and the providers of the certificate. in genric manar it can be suggested thet you need to change in the apache configuration file `SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` in a file located somewhere `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

for windows 10 you need to check it from  `SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"` and `SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"` if you are not using any other virtual host then you may consider updating `httpd-ssl.conf` from xampp [Xammp Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMO1i.jpg)

**EDIT**
cs_bundle file used to be required in prior versions of apache but now it is not required anymore. Most likely you only need origin and private key.it is optional for a later apache version.

**EDIT (after comment 1)**
open your `xamp panel -> config (click on )` from the dropdown you will find  `httpd-ssl.conf` alternatively you need to create a virtual-host within your xamp apache folder in windows. if you are using everything in a free manner, most likely within softoculus panel(which is your Cpanel) you may find to generate an SSL certificate using one click and it will set up everything for you.

**NOTE 1**
please note the free SSL will not provide any DV, OV, EV wildcard certificate but it will help you to test your app.

**NOTE 2**
there is another option to do your development and testing work using Cloudflare SSL [Cloudflare](https://dash.cloudflare.com/). the Cloudflare SSL provides quite a few more options to protect your website using their SSL (which is based on letsencrypt based. and their proxy works perfectly for testing purposes. within your softoculus panel, you may have options to integrate with Cloudflare SSL and proxy.

**NOTE 3**
Cloudflare manages their own CA and CAA record within their DNS so you can not update CAA or CA record on your own. For such reason, Cloudflare-generated SSL can be used within AWS Certificate manager but AWS-generated Certificate can not be used in Cloudflare.

**Edited With A note**
[YOu will get some options to upload certificate somewhere with in your just like I am getting an option here within OCI's layer 7 proxybased loadbalancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJpTm.jpg)

**NOTE 4**
ref: [cloufflare SSL Doc](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/)
ref: check some blog and howtos for ssl for local pc
ref: [setting apache in ubuntu like system](https://www.arubacloud.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-https-protocol-with-apache-2-on-ubuntu-20-04.aspx)
ref: [setting apache from digital ocean blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps)
ref: [SSL Self signed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/certmanage/)
ref : [SSL Configuration in OEL RHEL CentOS like operating system](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/obe-apache-install/#configure-your-tls-ssl-certifi)

Comment: Thanks for replying, @CADENTIC. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand a word from what you wrote. This whole server thing is new to me so I have no idea what Apache is or what is `httpd-ssl.conf`. Also my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: i thought you were using mac but most likely you have an option to enable ssl (free) or copy paste those keys in your cpanel softoculus etc.